# How do you preseed an ssh key?

Tags: ssh, 13.10, preseed

I tried this:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string mkdir -p /target/root/.ssh
d-i preseed/late_command string cp /cdrom/id_rsa.pub /target/root/.ssh/authorized_keys
d-i preseed/late_command string chmod -R go-rwx /target/root/.ssh
```

(I'm using a USB installer and I put id_rsa.pub in the root directory of the USB drive.)

The /root/.ssh directory is not created and the installer complains that the chmod command failed (not surprising if the directory doesn't exist).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can only preseed one late command. And you must specify `in-target` before your commands.

So put your commands on one line, separate them with a `;` before each command and add `in-target`.

Comment: It would explain the behavior I'm seeing if only the last late_command takes effect. Let me try that. I don't think I can run the command in-target, though, because I need to copy the key from the install media.